# ActionSupport not getting triggered

Tags: visualforce, apex

My action support is not getting triggered at all when I put it in my VF page. I looked at similar problems and changing the events but nothing seems to be doing the trick.

//suppose my object is called coffecup. This is a generic code, there may be small syntax error although probably not the problem.The rerender attribute rerenders coloumns on the pageblock table holding the coffecupSize and coffecupshape fields.The debug log shows that the setCoffeeCupSizeandShape method is not being entered at all
VF

```
<apex:column rendered="{!ifaccesible}">
                  <apex:facet name="header">Coffee Cup Colours</apex:facet>
                  <apex:outputField value="{!coffecup.colours}">  //A lookup field on the custom object
                            <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" action="{!setCoffeeCupSizeandShape}" rerender="coffecupSize, coffecupShape" />   
                            <apex:inlineEditSupport /> 
                  </apex:outputField>
</apex:column>
```

Controller

```
public void setCoffeeCupSizeandShape
{
        if (coffecup.colour == red) 
            CoffeeCupSize = large;
            coffeeCupShape = round; 

}
```

Comment: better chance to have this answered at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/

Comment: you might have validation error in page immediate = true try adding.

Comment: Thanks. Accidentally posted the question in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

`apex:outputField` has no onchange event support. You need to use `apex:inputField`.
If you need `apex:outputField` here, look at [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/9445)